# How to access a specific Wagtail page slug in a template

Tags: django, wagtail

I have created a number of Wagtail snippets to represent a link to a page and the text to display. E.g. I might want to have a link to *Contact us* in many many pages, always with the same text that can be edited by the user.

**models.py**

```
@register_snippet
class PageLink(models.Model):
    link_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    related_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        )

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('link_text'),
                PageChooserPanel('related_page'),
            ],
            heading = "Text and page",
        )
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.link_text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Page link"
        verbose_name_plural = "Page links"


register_snippet(PageLink)
```

**templatetags/link_tags.py**

```
@register.inclusion_tag("snippets/your_harmony_link.html", takes_context=True)
def links(context):
    return {
        'links': PageLink.objects.all(),
        'request': context['request'],
    }
```

**your_harmony_link.html**

```
{% for link in links %}
{{ link.url }} * {{ link.text }}
    <p>
        <a href="{{ link.url }}">
            {{ link.text }}
        </a>
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

I really just want to show one url here but I am looping through them just to sure I have got the model right. When the page is displayed I see all of the links as expected, but I can only see the *link.text*, not the *link.url*

[EDIT]: this has been solved (see comment), but the question remains:

How can I get the url for a particular link? There does not seem to be a key on a PageLink or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the url on the related_page? eg: `{{ link.related_page.link_url }}`? I don't have a wagtail project handy to check if that's actually an answer or not...

Comment: @JonClements No. That doesn't seem to be it

Comment: just tried link.related_page.url and its works. Sorry being dense